# text on top of image css

Tags: css, html

I am trying to place a div with text on top of an image but for some reason it doesn't work. My code is:

```
<div id="pics">     
  <div class="inner">
      <a href=".." target="_blank"><img src=".." class="pic" height="310" width="310"></a>
    <div class="cover">blah blah</div>      
  </div>
</div>
```

my CSS is:

```
 #pics{  
  overflow:hidden;
  display:block;
}

.inner a{
  position:relative;
  margin:3px;
  padding:10px;
  top:10px;
}

.inner{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cover{  
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
   color: white;
  left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 top: 0px;
}
```

I have tried many things but it doesn't seem to work. I might have messed up my cs somewhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're targetting an ID and not a class.

In other words, in the CSS you have the definition for an ID (`#cover`) and the HTML code has a class:

```
<div class="cover">blah blah</div>
```

Either change the HTML to have an ID:

```
<div id="cover">blah blah</div>
```

or change the CSS to target the class name:

```
.cover{  
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-style: solid 5px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

You are giving the `.cover` a width and height of 100%, but absolute positioned elements don't really "understand" that, so I suggest changing it to:
(place the left, bottom and right to the edges, this will fit the div as 100% width and height of the relative parent)

```
.cover{  
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-style: solid 5px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: It works better now but the size of the "cover" div is greater than that of the picture. any idea why this is happening? I just fixed it using different values for top,bot,left,right

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the picture as background via the `background-image:` attribute.
You then could make your div clickable with `<div onclick="window.location="url";>`

In detail your css would look like this:

```
.image {
  width:310px;
  height:310px;
  background-image:url('pathtoimage');
}
```